# How do I add a local module to a meteor project

Tags: javascript, npm, meteor, ecmascript-6, openapi

I am using a js module generated using openapi-generator.

The meteor project was created with:

```
meteor create myapp
```

I have created the module I want to include in the myapp application from a yaml file with openapi-generator in a different folder as follows:

```
java -jar openapi-generator-cli-5.1.1.jar generate -i myAPI.yaml -g javascript -o javascriptMinimalApi
```

The yaml file looks like this:

```
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  description: "minimal example"
  version: 1.0.0
  title: My Minimal API
  termsOfService: http://swagger.io/terms/
tags:
  - name: My Api
    description: My Api Call
externalDocs:
  description: Learn more about our signature service
  url: example.org
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:7080
paths:
  /myCall:
    post:
      tags:
        - My Api
      summary: My Api Call
      description: My minimal call for testpurposes
      operationId: myCall
      responses:
        "202":
          description: successfully return
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/MyCall"
        "400":
          description: Invalid input
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: "#/components/schemas/Error"
components:
  schemas:
    MyCall:
      type: object
      required:
        - textField
      properties:
        textField:
          type: string
      xml:
        name: MyCall
    Error:
      description: An error occured
      type: object
      xml:
        name: Error
```

Then I've installed it as described in the generated readme:

```
cd /path/to/local/module/
npm install
```

and then globally linked for local development in the folder of the module as follows:

```
sudo npm link
```

In the folder of the meteor project in which I want to include the local module I linked it as follows as follows:

```
cd /path/to/meteor/project/
npm link /path/to/local/module/
```

When I try to start the project with `meteor` I always get the following error at the line where I try to instantiate an object from the module:

```
TypeError: MyMinimalApi.MyApiApi is not a constructor
```

I tried to include some functionalities of the local module in the `myapp/server/main.js` file of the meteor project. You can find it here:

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { LinksCollection } from '/imports/api/links';

function insertLink({ title, url }) {
  LinksCollection.insert({ title, url, createdAt: new Date() });
}

Meteor.startup(() => {
  // If the Links collection is empty, add some data.
  if (LinksCollection.find().count() === 0) {
    insertLink({
      title: 'Do the Tutorial',
      url: 'https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/creating-an-app'
    });

    insertLink({
      title: 'Follow the Guide',
      url: 'http://guide.meteor.com'
    });

    insertLink({
      title: 'Read the Docs',
      url: 'https://docs.meteor.com'
    });

    insertLink({
      title: 'Discussions',
      url: 'https://forums.meteor.com'
    });
  }

  var MyMinimalApi = require('my_minimal_api');
  var api = new MyMinimalApi.MyApiApi();
  var callback = function(error, data, response) {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } else {
      console.log('API called successfully. Returned data: ' + data);
    }
  };
  api.myCall(callback);
});
```

To start the meteor application I just type `meteor`in the project folder.

Since it should be ES6 I've also tried to use

```
import MyMinimalApi from 'my_minimal_api';
```

instead of

```
var MyMinimalApi = require('my_minimal_api');
```

but without success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There isn't a `MyAPI.MyClass` in the example?

Comment: I have changed it to `MyApi.MyCall`

Comment: May you share a [mcve] of what's exported from `my_local_module`?

Comment: Yes, I can do it, but I need a few minutes

Comment: @schande if your share a min. rep. example we may be able to help you